# How to supress SignOut prompt in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

In IdentityServer3 we had option to suppress/disable signout prompt using AuthenticationOptions's property called "EnableSignOutPrompt" (default is true). What is corresponding property in IdentityServer4? Or is there any other way I can disable signout prompt?

Answer (score 0):

[no longer supported](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/162)

Since identity server4 does not provide ui it does not support this.